# Utilização do else fora de um if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, else

Estava escrevendo um programa que me fornecesse todos os números primos entre 1 e um determinado número que deveria ser informado pelo usuário. Após diversos ajustes no código, cheguei a seguinte versão final, que aparentemente funciona como deveria funcionar:

```
from math import *
num = int(input("Informe o limite dos primos: "))
for i in range(1, num+1):
    for j in range(2, ceil(sqrt(i+1))):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(i, end = " ")
```

O código fornece a seguinte saída:

```
================ RESTART: C:\Users\usuario2\Desktop\Primos.py ================
Informe o limite dos primos: 20
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 
>>> 
================ RESTART: C:\Users\usuario2\Desktop\Primos.py ================
Informe o limite dos primos: 50
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 
>>> 
================ RESTART: C:\Users\usuario2\Desktop\Primos.py ================
Informe o limite dos primos: 100
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Entretanto reparei uma coisa muito curiosa: Eu tenho um `else` fora de um `if`. Como pode? ao meu ver, não deveria funcionar. Por que funciona?

Comment: No Python o `for` possui `else`.

Comment: @Anderson como assim?

Comment: @Wictor sim, eu fui fazendo alterações e testando até dar certo, mas agora quero entender como pode o else funcionar fora do if.

Comment: Sim, comentei, antes de ler a pergunta, agora estou curioso esperando a resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss :P +1

Comment: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

Comment: Como o @AndersonCarlosWoss ja disse, no `python` vc pode adicionar um `else` no final do for, exeperimente: `for x in range(0,10): print(x) else: print(x)`